# import wxPython fails when executing program with sudo

Tags: python, ubuntu, wxpython

I have an application.py that reads and writes to /dev/ttyUSB0 so it needs to be run as sudo to access the serial port.

The application also uses wxPython (top of the program uses import wx)

The program launches as expected and runs correctly (except without proper permissions for the serial port) when launched from the command line without using sudo.

However, when using sudo, an error occurs:

```
File "application.py", line 35, in <module> 
   import wx
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wx'
```

It there an environment setting needed?  Why won't the application find wx when running under sudo?

Comment: $ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal

Comment: sudo apt-get install python-wxtools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-wxtools is already the newest version (3.0.2.0+dfsg-8build1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: An answer to this question posted by danzel is described here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1268870/python-module-not-found-in-sudo-mode-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: You could try adding the user to the `tty` group or `dialout` or whatever `group` /dev/ttyUSB0 belongs to. Then the need for sudo should disappear